# How to transform data when we have comma separated values in csv format file in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have an excel csv format data set with the following data:

**Columns**: id,    product_name,                             sales,     quantity, Profit

**Data:**     1, "Novimex Executive Leather Armchair, Black","$3,709.40",  9, -$288.77

When I am trying to insert these records from stage to snowflake table, data is getting shifted from `product name` column because we have comma separated `, Black` and similarly for following columns data are getting shifted. After loading the data it is looking like as per below:

```
+----+-------------------------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| id |            product_name             | sales  | quantity | Profit  |
+----+-------------------------------------+--------+----------+---------+
|  1 | "Novimex Executive Leather Armchair | Black" | $3       | 709.40" |
+----+-------------------------------------+--------+----------+---------+
```

Query used:

```
copy into orders_staging (id,Product_Name,Sales,Quantity,Profit) 
from
(select $1,$2,$3,$4,$5
from @sales_data_stage)
file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = ',' skip_header = 1 ENCODING = 'iso-8859-1');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Field Enclosure.

`FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"'`

If you have any issues with accounting styled numbers, remember to put `" "` around them too.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008pDcoRSAS/copying-csv-files-delimited-by-commas-where-commas-are-also-enclosed-in-strings

Additional documentation for Copy To

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-csv

Additional documentation on the Create File

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html

Comment: Thanks for this but when I tried enclosing number in double quotes for product name column and in file format written FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"'. I could see one additional column got added which is ```row``` and it has sequence and again all columns values got shifted by one

Comment: Based on your input using `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"'` should only generate 5 columns. Be sure you are using the same `"` symbol and not a unicode or RTF format. It maybe on the data preparation side you and you may need to concat " " on to your numbers manually in the select.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007LAoGTSA1/force-fieldoptionallyenclosedby-option-for-all-columns

Comment: ```copy into orders_staging (row_id,Product_Name,Sales,Quantity,Profit) 
from
(select $1,$2,$3,$4,$5
from @sales_data_stage)
file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = ',' skip_header = 1 ENCODING = 'iso-8859-1' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"');
```
I am using above command and it is appending ```row``` at the beginning

Comment: Without seeing the data obviously makes this tricky. Try testing a bit more on your end. Lot's of CSV options that may help explain the new issue.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-csv
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html

Comment: Happy to have helped.